# Can I generate a unique id like this?

Tags: java

I'm learning on a springboot project, and I'm wondering if I can get the address of its object using the timestamp + hascode return value of the business class. Is that ok?

I don't think it's easy to test, so I bring up the question and hope somebody thinks about whether it works

Comment: you can try datetimestamp with mill seconds + uuid, in spring hashcode of business class object will be same always, because by default it will be singleton bean

Comment: This is unlikely to be unique. You'd probably be better off just using a timestamp if it had high enough resolution.

Comment: What's your purpose to generate such an id? through the object reference can act as the address which can be compared by `==` or `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

For using timestamp, it has chances to be duplicated,

For using object hashcode, it has the chances to be duplicated as well if

1. more than one object reference is pointing to the same object.
2. the object hashCode method is overrided by developer like returning the object instance variable id other then its hashCode in memory. (which is quite often as overriding the equals method will usually override hashCode as well)

I personally prefer you to use UUID instead

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
String uniqueId = uuid.toString() + "_" + objectReference.hashCode();
```

if time is needed, it is ok to concat another timestamp string behind hashcode and you can then use split function of String class to retrieve them as you want,
The UUID class provide a way to generate unique Id which is super rare to be duplicated.

reference:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-uuid